# Error in Measuring distance using QGIS?

Tags: coordinate-system

I am using the current Qgis 2.6.1 and having problems using the measuring distance function. The 'Measure Line' is giving me distances which is completely wrong and the scale shown was too big also. The message displayed was that the map "...defined by Geographic Coordinate System but the map extent suggest it is actually Projected Coordinate System...". I tried rectifying it using the Project Properties menu but still no good.

It was alright when I used  the same data in the previous version (2.6.0)
The CRS = WGS 84.

Comment: [Check this out](http://gis.stackexchange.com/a/126538/5666) maybe it will help. You need to provide more details about your project settings and CRSs of layers in order to get helpful answer.